# Pré visualização do site nas rede sociais

Tags: vue.js, seo

Estou desenvolvendo uma SPA utilizando Vue.js, utilizando vue-router e para o Google, pelo que andei pesquisando, ele consegue indexar o conteúdo gerado via javascript. Agora para as redes sociais, por exemplo o Facebook, quando vamos compartilhar um link no post ele gera uma pré-visualização da página que será exibida no link.

O Facebook e outras redes sociais, conseguem renderizar o site com o conteúdo sendo gerado via javascript?

No minha aplicação não terei esse problema pois estou fazendo dentro de tema em Wordpress e estou utilizando o header do próprio WP `<?php wp_head(); ?>`, mais fiquei com essa dúvida.

Se não for uma aplicação que precise ser totalmente separada do back-end, como fica? Será necessário utilizar um prerender?

Comment: No ponte que tange o SEO o principal é vc fazer as Tags do protocolo OpenGraph. Aqui vc pode ver a documentação oficial http://ogp.me/ outro link de referência sobre OG Tags https://tableless.com.br/utilizando-meta-tags-facebook/

Comment: @hugocsl Quanto a isso tranquilo, a minha dúvida é se o site será renderizado na pré visualização, já que as Tags serão atualizadas/geradas via javascript